# How to get the first value in textbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

how can i get the first value in a text box and place it to a label. Example, I want to get the word "look" in the textbox that I input was "look like".

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: You want to get the first word in a textbox? Where WORD is defined as a consecutive series of characters separated by the subsequent series by a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use substring, this will split the string or aka your textbox.

This takes two params, The starting index of the string and the 2nd param is the length. I have put str.indexof in the 2nd param to get the index of where the space is.

```
dim str as string
Label1.Text = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(" "))
```

This code is not tested, I only used visual basic for a little bit when i was 12.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply `split` the value by `" "` space and take the first one from result array

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
lable1.Text = textBox1.Text.Split(" ").first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textboxValue = Textbox.Text;
str = textboxValue.Split(" ").first();
```